# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is a problem I've been having with `d3.js` and `d3.min.js`. For `d3.min.js`, it says that the problem is at `'ia   @ d3.min.js:3'` and `'u @   d3.min.js:1'`. These are both functions that take `n` as a parameter. It is difficult to read the code because it is very compact code. I am wondering if this is a parameter issue? Either way, I can't seem to figure out where to begin fixing it.

I also can't seem to find other questions on here that deal with my problem specifically. This 'unexpected token' is something that seems to have come with the code itself.

For the record, I am trying to play around with [this code](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025), using my own JSON file.

Comment: Instead of using d3.min.js, use the full source. That way you can see what's going on in a readable fashion. You can get the full source via the zip located on d3js.org front page: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/releases/download/v3.5.12/d3.zip

Comment: @Quy I receive the same error when I use the full source, which leads me to believe it is a parameter issue

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation here
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki
It is necessary to declare the charset as utf8 when using the d3 library.

Eg your script tag should look like this:

```
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: I've done this already, and I've added '<meta charset="utf-8">' to the top, as well.

Comment: Could be a collision with some other library you are using then. Are you able to construct a fiddle to highlight the problem?

Comment: this is what I'm working with: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Mg7ksn6mSH. I'm also using express with my application (which uses Jade, though my index.jade page says 'include index.html', so it should be a non-issue). I'm new to js so let me know if I'm using the fiddle incorrectly

Comment: Is there a page you can link to which exhibits this error?